# How do I get sum of multiple SELECT COUNT statements?

Tags: sql

I am using the following to return the count of multiple tables onto one row:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(Table1.Column1) 
   FROM Table1)                  AS Table1Column1Count,
  (SELECT COUNT(Table2.Column1) 
   FROM Table2)                  AS Table2Column1Count;
```

The above is working successfully, but my next step is to get a total of the results.  I am asking if there is a way to return the sum value as an additional column of output within this SQL statement rather than running a separate SQL statement.  And I need to do it using Standard SQL.  In practice, it is actually 10+ SELECT COUNTS so I would like to avoid running that twice.  I realize I can do that in the UI, and may end up doing that, but I wanted to explore this option first.

I have tried putting "+" between SELECT COUNT statements with AS TOTAL, and that works to get the total, but I am trying to get the individual table counts as well as the total to return on a single row of output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(Table1.Column1) FROM Table1) +
  (SELECT COUNT(Table2.Column1) FROM Table2)  AS Total;
```

Aliasses cannot be added so you will have to add (`+`) before adding aliasses.

When you want the individual totals, and the grand total

```
SELECT 
   Table1Column1Count, 
   Table2Column1Count,
   Table1Column1Count + Table2Column1Count as Total
FROM (
   SELECT 
     (SELECT COUNT(Table1.Column1) FROM Table1)  AS Table1Column1Count,
     (SELECT COUNT(Table2.Column1) FROM Table2)  AS Table2Column1Count
) subquery
```

Comment: you certainly answered the question, and very quickly!  thank you so much.  So as a follow up, can you tell me if this will work with EF so that it will work with SQL, Oracle, MySQL, etc.?  Or is any of this proprietary to MS SQL?

Comment: This is very standard SQL syntax, and it works in MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL.   I only think that when using Oracle you have to add `FROM DUAL` because Oracle **needs** the FROM in every select statement.

Comment: See: [DBFIDDLE for MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46a4a0e715d81e216607271d568d82c9),  [for MSSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d5bfb4cabe72e6256a64593c00dd5a93), and [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f1854612212628d32345cee5297435d2)

Comment: Excellent.  you have been a tremendous help.  many thanks

Comment: When asking (other) questions about SQL, please add the DBMS you are using. (and try to create a DBFIDDLE will help too )